# Sharepoint provider hosted app with Azure hosting

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Currently I am working with Sharepoint provider hosted app. My app is working fine but when add remote event receiver, I can not able to debug it. And also not able to get context.

I referred these links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381(v=office.15).aspx

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220043(v=office.15).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn275975(v=office.15).aspx
```

I am using Azure for web application hosting. My app is working properly by "Start" from visual studio, but getting error in Output:

> Cannot register Services/AppEventReceiver.svc on Windows Azure Service
>   Bus: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
>   just getting this error

But app is getting installed successfully each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check Service Bus connection type. 
At the moment there are two types of connection: SAS and ACS.

[image: SAS connection.]

To debug remote event receivers you should use ACS connection type.
You can check connection type in Azure Portal.
Unfortunately, you can't create ACS connection within Azure Portal.
You can create ACS connection with Azure Powershell.

```
New-AzureSBNamespace 'Service_Bus_Name' -CreateACSNamespace $ true -NamespaceType Messaging
```

[image]

You can read my full step-by-step manual here: 
http://blog.virtosoftware.com/2014/12/creating-and-debugging-of-remote-event.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy Azure Service bus and copy-paste secret key to Visual Studio(use google or screen shots [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/234432/is-it-possible-to-debug-and-test-my-remote-event-receivers-without-using-azure-s))

AFAIK - currently in 2018 - powershell commands for Service Bus creation are deprecated. What You can do to create Azure Service Bus - is use templates:

- go to [Create a Service Bus namespace using an Azure Resource Manager template](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-resource-manager-namespace) page
- press "Deploy to Azure" button, log into Azure, fill details and Your service-bus would be created automatically