# Is it possible to Debug and Test my remote event receivers without using Azure Service Bus

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, azure, azure-service-bus, service-bus

I am working on a SharePoint online project, and the current customer has an Azure VM to host the Remote Event Receivers. now in previous projects which i worked on, the customers use to have Azure subscriptions, where inside Azure web portal, i can create a service bus as follow:-

[image]

Then inside my Provider Hosted app project inside Visual Studio 2015, i can enter the service bus details as follow (right click the Project inside VS>> Properties >> SharePoint tab):-

[image]

this allowed me to debug my remote event receiver code, inside visual studio. but as i mentioned before for the current project, the customer has an Azure VM, and not an Azure subscription, **so is there a way i can create an Azure Service Bus inside Azure VM ?** and use it inside my visual studio project?

If the answer, is No (i can not create a service bus inside Azure VM), **then is there a way i can debug and test my Remote Event Receiver inside Visual Studio 2015, without having to specify Azure service BUS or other Service Bus connection strings??** so i just develop my RER >> click Run inside my visual Studio >> and have my RER running so i can test/debug it (same case when debugging server-side ER)??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge you need to have Azure subscription account and Azure service bus in order to debug your remote event receiver.
And I don't think you can create Azure service Bus inside your VM.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. it is really weird, so Microsoft assume that any customer need to have an Azure subscription account, otherwise remote event receivers can not be test/debugged ? second point now we as a software development company have an Azure subscription account, so can we created a service bus inside our account to test our customers' remote event receivers ? based on my knowledge we could is this correct?

Comment: In the end it's a marketing thing. Regarding your comment question: the client needs to have the subscription (as far as I know); meaning it has to be under the same account.

Comment: @JohnKelheim Now i created a new free Azure account using my Hotmail account, and inside the free Azure account, i create new service bus, then i add the service bus inside my Provider Hosted App, and it get debugged and deployed inside the sharepoint online site. so seems i can use any Azure Account to test any Provider hosted apps for any office 365 account ....

Answer (score 1):

you can debug remote event receiver in ***on-premise*** server with Visual Studio without the need to configure Azure Service Bus.
but, you have to use Microsoft Azure Service Bus for debugging remote event receiver for ***SharePoint online***.

please check the this link for more details
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/debug-and-troubleshoot-a-remote-event-receiver-in-a-sharepoint-add-in